# HTML5 Page visibility- visibility state

Tags: html, performance

The prerender state and unloaded state seem to be confused to me.

Prerender: the document is loaded off-screen and not visible

unloaded: if the document is to be unloaded, then this value will be returned

Say the "prerender" will do the work to load the resource when the visibility is not visible, does "unloaded" do the same thing? or "unloaded" will return either the visibility state is hidden or visible. It returns when the document is to be unloaded.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

`prerender` and `unloaded` are both values for the `visibilityState` attribute (in addition to `hidden` and `visible`) and can be seen as start and end points of the loading process.

If the page is being prepared by the browser in a background tab but not fully loaded then the `visibilityState` may be `prerender`. Once fully loaded it will change to `hidden` or `visible`. When the user closes the tab, the `visibilityState` should be `unloaded` while the page is being removed from memory. These two values are both optional however, and in practice I haven't been able to get browsers to return either of them.